# How to remove Everyone and NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users from SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

In Groupcollection these groups are not coming. Can you please let me know how can we remove this from SharePoint site?

```
GroupCollection groupColl = website.SiteGroups;
client.Load(groupColl);
client.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (Group grp in groupColl)
{
    string groupname = Convert.ToString(grp.Title);
    if(Groupname == "Everyone")
    {
        client.Load(grp);
        client.ExecuteQuery();
        groupColl.Remove(grp);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must not remove Authenticated Users group grom local Users group, because many things will fail. For example, batch jobs, services, logons without profile loading will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

the security risk imposed by NT-Authority is bigger than the real Trojan. I bought brand new lanovo,set it up,its not sheared pc within the few day, 2 much warning coming from McAfee about so many computer trying connecting to my home network.and my pc not running well, resetted the window, bitlocker locker on C;\, set firewall policy no domain connection, I removed and block NT-Authority in firewall and replaced the SiD in the local principle including NT-Au., it was working well but the the problem is back, was trying uninstalling printer but it was not possible. I sign in with finger print,and soon realised that nothing is working if I click any apps, I check the security on any apps on the screen and it is only administrators got permission on all the apps on the screen, I realised the window am seeing had been created, not only one but 2, McAfee is working well but is not on the window and seeing, My pc was actually in the hand of administrators,I went into McAfee setting, More than 8 connection had been set up, I clear cookies and TEP files, I scan nothing wrong, I checked My setting and I was surprised, a special Temporary files was Listed under me, Too much, it took time but 2 file can not be deleted, it is this is nsk34FF.tem and nslAA4E.tem, McAfee said it can not be shredded, it was saying that I do not have permission to delete it, but these tem. files was in explore, but if you just open document or pictures, it is not visible with our eyes but visible in McAfee threader, the day before, I went to registry and found network 2 was fully setup and this file nsk34FF.tem was there,detai of that in McAfee saying it network driver. all whatever I was doing was store there on that tep, this evening I tried to reset the window and was not possible, it keeps saying we run into problems, this administrators in window NT-AUTHORITY Does not matter if you remove, they will set another window and you will have no permission to change settings, it does not mater what security you have, you will join Domain network without knowing,I disable all work group and I found my pc was connected inside McAfee safe guard network.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the group.  It is a security risk leaving it there

This design is a HUGE security problem though. As long as "authenticated users" is in the users group then user accounts and service accounts will have more permission then they should.

Example - the IIS Worker process. Even if you create a login that is not within the domain users or local users group which the application pool will run as - it's still a member of "authenticated users" which then puts the login into the users group. The result is that your public facing web server is now running an IIS worker process that serves the web AND has permission to write to the root of the server's C:/ drive!!! You see the problem here I'm sure!.

There should absolutely be a way to remove the "NT Authority\Authenticated Users" group from the server's local users group so the server can be hardened.